# Creating List of images from a list of images

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, scikit-image, os.walk

I have a list(display_train_set)containing 200 images. which i made using code below. I now need to make a list containing 40 list, where each list has 5 images from display_train_images. Please help guys i am new to python.

```
  dataset_dir = "FaceDataset" 
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dataset_dir):
    path = root.split(os.sep)
    img_dir = root + "/"
    i = 0
    for file in files:
        img = imread(img_dir + file)
        img_resized = resize(img, (200, 200))
        if i <= 4:
            display_test_set.append(img)
        else:
            display_train_set.append(img)

        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will split your input list in steps of `item_count`:

```
def group_list_items(input_list, item_count):
  result_list = list()
  for i in range(0, len(input_list), item_count):
    result_list.append(input_list[i:i + item_count])

  return result_list
```

[Try it online](https://repl.it/repls/WiltedIndianredFiber)

In your case:

```
grouped_images = group_list_items(display_train_set, 5)
```

Results in `grouped_images` containing 40 lists, each containing 5 images